# measure luminanace with lux meter

Tags: light, lumen

can we measure luminance in cd/ m² with a lux meter?
I measured illuminance of 35 lux. and since cd = lux*distance² I took some distance of 30 cm and got 3.15 cd.
I know that my led-grid surface is 100cm² then I deduce that the luminance is 315cd/m² is my idea correct?
if yes which surface should I take into consideration the led-grid surface (as I have done) or the surface of lux meter sensor

Comment: Target brightness for a standard monitor is 120cd/m². 315 sounds rather excessive. What's supposed to be the point of this exercise?

Comment: this is actually a led grid used to stimulate eyes in medical context

Comment: Then I'm not sure what this could possibly have to do with photography.

Comment: not in terms of context but it is still a question about light acquisition

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with photography.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the right situation luminance can be converted to illuminance. But I don't think you have the right conditions... the light source has to be diffused/integrated (such as with an integration sphere) and the only source of light.

In that case the formula for cd/m² is Luminance = (illuminance x reflectance)/π

You might be better off using a camera and converting the exposure value to the luminance value.
[https://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~phiscock/astronomy/light-pollution/luminance-notes-2.pdf](https://www.ee.ryerson.ca/%7Ephiscock/astronomy/light-pollution/luminance-notes-2.pdf)

Comment: the attached document seems to go through a method for luminance determination